# Need to add a new row after html is placed into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape a website for two weeks now. I first started by looking for a hidden API and could not find one. I then just started scraping the html directly using requests and BeautifulSoup. The website is a yacht website and each yacht and it's data on it is in its own webpage. After many trials I decided I would scrape the urls for each yacht and place them in their own dataframes (so I wouldn't be scraping 700+ urls in one script) with two columns, the yacht specific part of the link and the full url. Each dataframe contains a range of yacht names. For example, the first dataframe is all of the yachts with names that start with A-C.

Each yacht has 32 different data points, but because 16 of those will be the column headers, I only need every other one.

I can successfully scrape one single yacht into a dataframe with the correct structure (see code below)

```
  import pandas as pd

  import requests
  
  import time 

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  url = 'https://www.superyachtfan.com/yacht/ace/'

  r = requests.get(url=url, verify=False)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')    

  table = soup.find('div', id = 'main')

  column_headers = (['Name', 'Length', 'Guests', 'Crew', 'Builder', 
                     'Designer', 'Interior Designer', 'Year', 'Speed',
                     'Engines', 'Volume', 'IMO', 'Price', 
                     'Annual Running Cost', 'Owner', 'Captain'])
  
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_headers)

  data = []

  for tr in table.find_all('tr'):

        for td in tr.find_all('td')[1::]:
    
              for item in td:
        
                    item = td.text.replace("\n", "")
              
              data.append(item)

  df = df.append(pd.Series(data, index=column_headers), 
  ignore_index=True)
```

[Output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYm0V.png)

I now run into the problem of having to iterate through my dataframes and store each yacht data on a different row. If anyone could help with this it would be so greatly appreciated.

This is how I have my current dataframes set up with the links in them. I need to add the column headers after the first two link columns and the append the yacht data to each row while the yacht specific link and full link stay in the first two columns.
[The dataframe structure I am trying to write to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZAte.png)

Comment: Please don't upload your code in image form, a good general rule is: If it's text then you can put it in a code block! Also small tip: [mre] <- this will get you better and faster answers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please no pictures for what can be posted as text, see [ask] for guidance.

Comment: Don't use pandas much, but it seems to me its not a good format for gathering information incrementally. Rather its a format for analysing information efficiently after its all gathered. Thus I would probably gather the info in regular python objects like a list of dict or some such. Then I would convert to a dataframe for analysis. Maybe store it in a parquet file as a df after its gatehred.

Comment: I echo what @AndrewAllaire recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an inspiration to work with `pandas` - based on a `list` or `series` to iterate, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to merge your collected table results into one `dataframe`.

##### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

urls = [
    'https://www.superyachtfan.com/yacht/attessa-v/',
    'https://www.superyachtfan.com/yacht/ace/'
]


pd.concat(
    [
        pd.read_html(
            requests.get(url, headers={'user-agent':'some-agent'}).text
        )[0].set_index([0]).T
        for url in urls
    ], 
    ignore_index=True
)
```

Depending on the actual results required, cosmetics of the value can be done or, to be more specific, work directly with `BeautifulSoup`.